# How to remove <br>s that are in the beginning of the string?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my table:

```
-- mytb
+----+---------------------------+
| id |         content           |
+----+---------------------------+
| 1  | <br> whatever ..          |
| 2  | whatever <br> whatever .. |
| 3  |    <br> whatever ..       |
| 4  | <br> whatever <br> ..     |
+----+---------------------------+
```

I need to remove all `<br>`s that are in the beginning of the string. I can specify it using `^` in PHP regex. How can I do the same in MySQL?

```
update mytb set content = trim(content)
```

It just removes the surrounded spaces.

Comment: wich version of mysql are you using ?

Comment: `set content = REPLACE(content, '<br>', '')` ?

Comment: Do you want to remove `<br>` only at the start of the string or all `<br>`'s in the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a query like this:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('<br>Hello<br>world<br>','^(<br>)*(.*?)(<br>)*$','\\2');
```

**Sample**

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('<br>Hello<br>world<br>','^(<br>)*(.*?)(<br>)*$','\\2');
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| REGEXP_REPLACE('<br>Hello<br>world<br>','^(<br>)*(.*?)(<br>)*$','\\2') |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Hello<br>world                                                         |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('Hello<br>world<br>','^(<br>)*(.*?)(<br>)*$','\\2');
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| REGEXP_REPLACE('Hello<br>world<br>','^(<br>)*(.*?)(<br>)*$','\\2') |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Hello<br>world                                                     |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('<br>Hello<br>world','^(<br>)*(.*?)(<br>)*$','\\2');
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| REGEXP_REPLACE('<br>Hello<br>world','^(<br>)*(.*?)(<br>)*$','\\2') |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Hello<br>world                                                     |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('Hello<br>world','^(<br>)*(.*?)(<br>)*$','\\2');
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| REGEXP_REPLACE('Hello<br>world','^(<br>)*(.*?)(<br>)*$','\\2') |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Hello<br>world                                                 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

Comment: Mariadb here and he asks for mysql.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT REPLACE('content','<br>','') FROM MYTB
WHERE content LIKE '<br>%'
```

Comment: He said starting <br> not all <br>

Comment: `replace()` will replace _all_ occurences in the string. I.e. it will replace both '<br>' from the record with id=4

Answer (score 0):

You can use REGEXP  in MYSQL:

```
SELECT REPLACE('content','<br>','') as content  FROM table WHERE content REGEXP '^<br>'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN substr(content,1,4) ='<br>' 
            THEN substr(content,5,len(content))  
            ELSE content 
       END as content
```

Answer (score -1):

Use MYSQL substring with if condition.

```
SET content = TRIM
                (IF
                  (SUBSTRING
                     (TRIM(content), 1, 4) = '<br>',
                      SUBSTRING(TRIM(content), 5), content
                  )
                );
```

Answer (score -2):

MYSQL has a `substring` function that can be used:

```
UPDATE mytb SET content = SUBSTRING(content, 5)
WHERE content LIKE '<br>%'
```